# Save the selected latitude and longitude by user - Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a div with id `map`, this is showing the Google maps with a default latitude/longitude.

Now I want to let the user for example points his company office on the map and I need to save that latitude/longitude + the level of zoom, so the next time I could show the exact place that he has saved last time.

Here is my code:

```
var map_point = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -97); // Default latLng(USA)
$('#map').gmap({'center': map_point})
.bind('init', function(event, map) { 
    $(map).click( function(event) {
        var lat=event.latLng.lat();
        var lng=event.latLng.lng();
        $('#latlng').val(lat+','+lng);
    });
});
```

With the above code I can update my hidden input with id `latlng` as you're seeing in my above code, but this happens while the user `clicks` on the map, I don't want that to happen, I want something like `.drag` and on drag of the map the hidden input val gets updated.

Also, how I could save the `zoom` level so the next time I could add the option zoom to the map and show the exact saved place to the user?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach event handlers on map

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function(event) { 
   alert(event.latLng);
 });
// guess this will return latLng

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom-changed', function() { 
   alert(map.getZoom())
 });
// will return zoom

map.setCenter(latlng); // will set the center of the map
```

map is google map object and not the div